# Trying to upgrade my laptop SSD, 1mm too big to fit in the slot

Tags: ssd, upgrade, windows-installer

I have an MSI laptop with a Toshiba SSD 256GB (thnsnj256g8nu) and I want to upgrade it to an Evo 970 plus.

The old SSD fits perfectly but the new one doesn't, like it's 2mm bigger.

**New SSD**
[image: New SSD]

**Old Toshiba SSD**

[image: Old Toshiba SSD]

**The Problem**
[image: The problem]

**Why is it not compatible, and how can I know what items are compatible with my motherboard?
Should the new SSD fit in the motherboard?**

Comment: Does your laptop support B or M keyed M.2 devices?  You will have to take a look at the connector to determine this information.  Instead of submitting a comment you should provide the information within the body of your question.  *However, both SSDs are the identical length and width, which means the only possible explanation is due an incompatibility with M key.*  **It also looks like you are attempting to install the Samsung drive in the incorrect orientation.**

Comment: How to know if my laptop does support M or B? I have this MSI https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/ge62-2qf-apache-pro
Note: I just flipped the SSD so it fits slot separator

Comment: Visual inspection of the connector

Comment: Your link does not actually work.  What is the exact model number of your laptop?  It appears you are trying to replace a SATA M.2 drive with a NVMe M.2 which isn't going to work.

Comment: Laptop model: MIS GE62 2QF, The link is working

Comment: I clicked the link, page goes to a 404 error, the link you provided in your comment is not functional.  Comments are designed to be temporary.  if you had provided that information in the question you could correct the link.  The only recourse you have is to just delete the comment since the link is not valid and it cannot be edited.

Comment: That's wired, I tried on a website called https://www.browserling.com/ (Online interactive browser) and it worked: https://imgur.com/sTxbug7

Comment: First suggestion - remove the small sticker that covers the slot ... or fold it back to see inside ... And reading the manual it should fit - since nvme basically means pcie-interfdace cards .. which are supported .. except MSI can't write manuals ;-) Going by my own notebook from ASUS - the chips on the ssd face to you when you install them

Comment: "Note: I just flipped the SSD so it fits slot separator".  The two slots are not symmetric, exactly to prevent the shenanigans you attempted.  The SSD must be installed rightside up.  Your SSD and your socket are totally incompatible, one has the B key and one has the M key.  It's not a matter of 1mm physical fit, the electrical signals are different.

Comment: Better question: why didn't you do your research before buying a new SSD?

Comment: The connector is keyed differently. The key type identifies the drive type, and compatible drives. The keying is to stop you plugging in the wrong type of drive. The different key stopped you plugging in the wrong type of drive. Solution, buy the right type of drive, with a connector key that matches your laptop.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to the picture you posted, the old model you used was a Toshiba THNSNJ256G8NU and it's a SATA III SSD. It uses a "B+M" key edge connector, according to the picture you posted.

Here is what the "B+M" connector looks like:

[image]

Meanwhile, the new one you purchased and plan to replace it with is an NVMe SSD (Samsung Evo 970). It uses an "M" key connector.

The first thing you should check is whether your laptop supports NVMe SSDs or not. Many laptops only allow using SATA SSDs, only having a SATA III interface. Therefore, even if you can insert this new SSD into your M.2 slot somehow, it may not work at all.

I couldn't find full specifications of your laptop based on the model [you posted](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/ge62-2qf-apache-pro).

The best replacement for you is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07822Z77M).

Updated:

After digging a bit deeper, I found this file from [MSI](https://asset.msi.com/global/picture/faq/10012015@2018-0208-1152-303101@faq_01117_en.pdf), which declared that an "M" key SSD can only be used in an "M" key socket:

[image]

A bit deeper in the same document:

[image]

So based on the model you provided, you have 2 "B" key SSD slots, and 1 "M" key SSD slot. **However**, all three slots can only use SATA III SSDs. There is no way you can use an NVMe SSD at all.

So the one you have purchased (Samsung 970 EVO Plus) can't be used.

Comment: If the `GE62 2QF` notebook can support Socket 2 (B Key) and Socket 3 (M Key) based on the screenshot.  I base that statement on the fact you highlighted that specific text.  I suspect either the MSI screenshot is incorrect or we have the incorrect screenshot  However, there is no doubt, the author's current SSD is a M.2 SATA 3 (B&M Key)

Comment: I doubt that because the source was issued by MSI itself (from asset.msi.com). However, the one that Adam has purchased doesn't work with his laptop at all.

Comment: The screenshots are more confusing then helpful, which isn't you fault, but in one screenshot they indicate that Socket 3 is (M Key) but in the other they indicated the model has both (Socket 2 and Socket 3) and in the same screenshot indicates it only has SATA (Socket 2).  MSI isn't known for it's documentation (my own experience caught numerous erratas).

Comment: Wonderfully knowledgeable answer.

Answer (score 37):

You have an incompatible drive *and* are trying to insert it upside down!

Unfortunately M.2 is a horrible mess. In theory M.2 supports a bunch of different keyings, with each keying supporting a different combination of interfaces. The two keyings relavent for SSDs are keys "B" and "M".

Unfortunately the B and M keyings are almost, but not quite a mirror image of each other. In your case you got lucky that your slot was tight enough to prevent the incorrect insertion. I saw a similar post over on hardforum where someone actually managed to insert a SSD upside down.

In theory the key B pinout supports "PCIe ×2, SATA, USB 2.0 and 3.0, audio, UIM, HSIC, SSIC, I2C and SMBus", while the key M pinout supports "PCIe ×4, SATA and SMBus ". In practice the two interfaces we care about for SSDs are PCIe and SATA.

In practice slots that only support Sata M.2 SSDs are usually B keyed, slots that only support PCIe are usually M keyed and slots that support both are also usually M keyed. PCIe M.2 SSDs are usually M keyed, while SATA M.2 SSDs are usually double notched to fit both B and M slots.

Your slot is B keyed, which in practice means you need a SATA M.2 SSD. In principle a B key slot could support PCIe x2, but even if it does, it doesn't really help you because most PCIe M.2 SSDs are M keyed.

Comment: I wouldn't say they got lucky on the slot size. The person on the other site who managed to cram an M key upside down into a B slot was unlucky as that's not supposed to be possible without a lot of force and breaking of things.

Comment: Upvoted for "horrible mess".

Comment: Still not as bad as USB C.

Comment: A number of years ago I worked at a big-box computer store, and a customer came in asking for a 128MB PC-100 ram chip.  What he didn't tell the salesman was that it was for a laptop, which used the smaller SO-DIMM chips.  Easy mistake, anyone could have made it.  We would've gladly refunded it, but this guy decided he was gonna MAKE it fit.  He sawed the chip in half and filed a new notch in it to make it fit, predictably frying his laptop.  He brought it back demanding we pay for the damages, but obviously it was his fault so we didn't.  We framed the chip and mounted it on the wall.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman PC-100?!  A number of years indeed...

Answer (score 8):

The Samsung Evo 960 Plus drive has a PCIe Gen 3.0 x4, NVMe 1.3 interface. Your `Toshiba THNSNJ256G8NU` drive has a SATA 6.0 Gbps M.2 interface.

Your replacement drive would be a Samsung 860 Evo.

Comment: I was actually mistaken.  When I searched for `THNSNJ256G8NU` I got results for the incorrect drive on Amazon. `THNSNJ256G8NU` is actually a SATA M.2 drive which is the reason not fit in the slot.  **I have restored your original correct answer.**