# Will an M.2 M Key motherboard connector always support NVMe, or does NVMe support need to be explicitly stated in the manual?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, nvme, m.2

Apologies this may be a basic question, but after much reading of sometimes contradictory information I wanted to check whether my understanding is correct.

I'm upgrading a PC, and want to add M.2 storage as a boot drive.

Most of the guidelines I've read suggest to "read your motherboard manual to check it supports M.2 NVMe".

My manual states "1 x M.2 (M Key) Connector (support SATA SSD)". As you can see, no mention of NVMe.

However I've also seen claims that M Key slots always support NVMe, and that the whole point of the keyed slot is that incompatible hardware will not fit.

Based on what is printed in the manual, would you conclude that this motherboard does support NVMe M.2? Or would the manual need to explicitly state NVME?

My feeling is that I should install SATA/AHCI M.2 storage, but would like to confirm that I'm correct in this belief.

Comment: 1) What is the exact make and model of the motherboard? 2) Which operating system is the PC running?

Comment: In order to accurately answer your question you will have to provide us with more specific information.  What exactly are you referring to when you mention "SATA/AHCI M.2"?  You should be using AHCI unless you have a RAID configuration.

Comment: More details here: https://superuser.com/questions/1530474/trying-to-upgrade-my-laptop-ssd-1mm-too-big-to-fit-in-the-slot

Comment: Strictly speaking, M.2 isn't related to NVMe at all. It's just PCI Express (+ USB and others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M.2 is just the form factor. M.2 drives can come in SATA
versions and NVMe versions, which describes the bus they
use to electrically communicate with the other PC components.
SATA M.2 SSD drives and 2.5" SATA SSDs actually operate at virtually identical spec, while NVMe drives are much faster.

As the connector is defined as M.2 SATA, it might not support NVMe.
You are right in that NVMe has to be specifically included in
the description to be sure, but if it's not
included that still does not mean much beyond "be careful".

While it's true that M.2 NVMe SSDs for PCIe 3.0 x4 lane are all
M-keyed, this is also true for all fast SSDs.
The M-key just means that the controller supports fast SSD.

A modern M-key PCIe has a good chance of supporting NVMe,
while if it was made before 2016 it's unlikely to support NVME.

For a full verdict we will need to know what is your motherboard
model and when was the computer bought.

---

According to the article
[BioStar Racing B360 GT5S Motherboard – Video Review](https://www.modders-inc.com/biostar-racing-b360-gt5s-motherboard-video-review/):

> Two m.2 slots, one of which supports nVME or Intel Optane drives, the other supports both m.2 SATA or nVME storage.

This is supported by the
[Biostar B360 manual](https://www.biostar.com.tw/upload/Manual/Manual_new/IB36C-AHT_EN.pdf),
where there's one socket that has a chance : PCIE-M2_1,
described on page 12:

> **PCIE-M2_1: M.2 (Key M) Slot (x4 speed)**
>
> - The M.2 slot supports M.2 Type 2242/2260/2280/22110 SSD module. When installing M.2 SSD module, please place the screw and hex pillar to
>   correct position.
> - Support M.2 PCI Express module up to Gen3 x4 (32Gb/s).
> - Support Intel® Optane Technology.

[image]